# Is there an opportunity in PHPStorm the same abbreviation of Live Template to be expanded in different ways by tab and enter?

Tags: phpstorm, abbreviation, live-templates

For example I want abbreviation `php` to be expanded in two ways:

1) With Tab:

`<?php $END$ ?>`

2) With Enter:

`<?php
  $END$
?>`

I can't create the same abbreviation in one group.
I can create template with abbreviation `php` expanding with tab in one group and another template with the same abbreviation expanding with enter in another group.

But the problem is that when i print `php` and press Tab I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8giRw.png): the list of two snippets.

e.g the second snipped assignes to Enter also expands by Tab.

Is there an opportunity in PHPStorm the same abbreviation of Live Template to be expanded in different ways by tab and enter without any menus like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8giRw.png)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. [IDEA-67811](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-67811) asks for a way to assign shortcuts to individual live templates, please feel free to vote for it